# Calendar control to display next month

Tags: c#, asp.net

Added a Standard `Calendar` control, and now i need to click on the arrow so it shows the next month.

How can i implement this ?

For now, when i click on the arrow to display the next month it doesn't change. How can i implement this ?

Comment: The default control works fine when you click the next month arrow. What issue are you facing..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<asp:Calendar  
        ID="Calendar1"   
        runat="server"  
        NextPrevFormat="FullMonth"  
        SelectionMode="DayWeekMonth"  
        SelectMonthText="Month"  
        SelectWeekText="Week"  
        ForeColor="WhiteSmoke"  
        DayNameFormat="Full"  
        Font-Names="Book Antiqua"  
        Font-Size="Medium"  
        OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"  
        >
```

Comment: Where should i add the action for the `Calendar1_SelectionChanged `. This is a MVC project.